# How to route internet through SOCKS proxy running on iPhone?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, iphone, socks-proxy

I have a jailbroken iPhone 3GS that I have set up a SOCKS proxy on using the following command:

```
ssh -D 3333 ec2-user@ec2-12-345-678-910.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I would like to share this connection with other users on the local network (I don't necessarily care about using it on my iPhone). So far I have been unsuccessful.

Is there something I have to do in the terminal on my iPhone to share my tunnel? I would think that I should be able to just set the proxy settings to 192.168.1.234:1080 (the port I am going through and my IP address) and it would then redirect through the specified port (1080) at the specified device (my iPhone).

I also have an iMac (using it right now) that I have tried setting the proxy settings in System Preferences → Network → Advanced → Proxies to 192.168.1.234, but when I try to access the internet, I receive something along the lines of:

> Could not contact the server "google.com" [or whatever I am attempting to visit] because the server cannot be found

I have been able to successfully set up a tunnel on my iMac using `ssh -D` and connect to the internet, but I just set up the tunnel on my iMac and then tried to connect to it from my dad's iMac. The attempt was unsuccessful. I can not access the tunnel on my dad's iMac, only on my own.

So, I am wondering if maybe the port is by default closed to inbound connections? If so, how would I open a port to inbound connections?

Comment: You can setup a socks proxy in Internet Explorer (Lan settings - Advanced) and Firefox - this will give you an access to WWW. If you want to route multiple different protocols on a single socks tunnel - this cannot be done as far as i know.